# What is the word to refer unnecessary definition or adjective?

Tags: word-request

If I mention a skyscraper as a tall skyscraper, it is obvious that tall is not providing any extra value. I am wondering what is the word describing this type of unnecessary adjectives or more generally unnecessary definition?

Comment: It's generally referred to as redundancy. The word **tall** is redundant or pleonastic.

Comment: That's called **circular definition**.

Comment: @Lambie: 'Redundancy' is a completely different thing. For example, the 'round' in 'a round circle' is redundant.

Comment: @Void First, you can't  have a circular definition with an adjective and noun. You need a verb. Secondly, this is called redundancy: https://writingcooperative.com/3-types-of-redundant-writing-and-how-to-avoid-them-1f83ff70064b The word tall is redundant. Let's not confuse writing and logic. Wikipedia: In linguistics, redundancy refers to information that is expressed more than once.[

Answer (score 3):

The noun phrase 'a tall skyscraper" could mean "a building that is even taller than many buildings labeled skyscrapers" just as "a tall basketball player" could mean a person taller than the average of that already tall group.

If such a relative comparison is not intended, if the writer merely means to emphasize that this skyscraper is tall, as all skyscrapers must be then it is a **redundancy**, since "skyscraper" means "a particularly tall building". Sometimes a redundancy can be good style, as a form of emphasis, but most often it is not.

This is not a circular definition, because it is not a definition at all, but a circular definition is generally redundant.

I would not call this a tautology, although it might technically be one. I use "tautology" for a self-evident statement that says the same thing in two different ways, or has two alternatives which are opposites, so one must be true, such as:

> - All those who do not go will stay
> - That which is not true is false.
> - My name is John, or else it isn't.

Mostly I use and see "tautology" in formal logic, or where things are being analyzed in a manner similar to that used in formal logic.

Comment: A tautology requires a verb, in my humble opinion.

Comment: All my examples of tautologies in the answer and such classics as "A equals A"  have verbs.

Comment: "a tall skyscraper" does not contain a verb, I think was Lambie's point

Comment: @gotube  Yes and i said I would not call it a tautology, attempting to refute or at least counter another answer that described it as one.

Answer (score 2):

It is called a ***tautology***:

> the saying of the same thing twice over in different words, generally considered to be a fault of style
> e.g.
> They arrived *one after the other* *in succession*.

([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=tautology%20meaning&safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk03slxgb1JAoY-9xinbolPIYeEh6oA%3A1624808215837&source=hp&ei=F5vYYNL1MJSNhbIPy8SOiAM&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYNipJ_Her06TAmsQlu2U6U6KRdiTCinZ&oq=tautology&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIICAAQsQMQkQIyBwgAELEDEEMyBQgAEJECMgcIABCHAhAUMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoECCMQJzoICAAQsQMQgwE6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOgoIABCxAxCDARBDOgoILhDHARCjAhBDOgUIABCxAzoFCC4QsQM6CggAEIcCELEDEBQ6BAguEAo6BwguELEDEAo6AgguUPcEWM4SYNMdaABwAHgAgAFziAGcBpIBAzcuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=gws-wiz))

Tautology can sound serious but be hilarious sometimes:

> - to over-exaggerate
> - frozen ice
> - The evening sunset

Some consider a tautology expressions like ***working mum*** (I find it so amusing!).